# FBLoginViewDelegate methods are never called when I log in

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a ViewController with a button

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginButton;
```

In ViewDidLoad I set the delegate of the button

```
self.loginButton.delegate = self;
```

and then I implement the delegate methods

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    NSLog(@"loginViewShowingLoggedInUser");
}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    NSLog(@"loginViewFetchedUserInfo");
}
```

Naturally when I click on the login button it takes me through the Facebook login process. The problem is, when Facebook returns to my app, the delegate methods are not called. Yet when I look on `https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications` I see that I have logged in.

So how do I get the delegate methods to be invoked? And yes I have the declaration

```
@interface MyFacebookViewController : UIViewController <FBLoginViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Did you add the facebook URL handler to your application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: in your app delegate?

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I was missing. Will you please rewrite as a response so I may mark the thread as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2#button-response), you need to call the Facebook URL handler from your application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: in your app delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    // You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed

    return wasHandled;
}
```